# Необычный глюк ввода / вывода

Tags: c++, вывод, ввод

Посмотрите мой код и подскажите почему до второго ввода дело не доходит, а происходит преждевременный вывод в последней строке  и выводит что попало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 255;

int main(){
    std::string string, substring;
    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];

    std::cout << "enter string: ";
    std::cin >> buff;
    string = buff;
    std::cout << "enter substring: ";
    std::cin >> buff; // здесь до ввода не доходит, а выполняется вывод в строке 20......
    substring = buff;

    size_t tmp = 0;

    tmp = string.find(substring);
    std::cout << tmp;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: только за последний месяц я видел несколько подобных вопросов. Суть в том, что `std::cin >> buff;` вводит *одно* слово, а слова разделяются пробелами. Используйте getline или аналоги.

Comment: спасибо хороший человек

Comment: Почему бы сразу не вводить в string и substring? Зачем нужен этот странный буфер buff?

Comment: @KoVadim: Почему бы не как ответ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что `cin`, как и `scanf %s` читает до пробельного разделителя.

Чтобы прочитать строку целиком можно воспользоваться `gets` или `cin.getline`.